# Mostrar imagen cargada con el administrador

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo Pillow instalado, Django 2.1 y un modelo con un campo ImageField que sitúa las imágenes cargadas en el directorio "images".

En el formulario desde el administrador puedo cargar la imagen y ésta es almacenada en dicho directorio (/media/images), pero cuando intento cargar (o pinchar el enlace) en el navegador la url a la que apunta la imagen , me muestra en éste el mensaje de error "Page not Found", en resumen, que dicho enlace o no es valido o no me lo deja cargar por alguna razón.

Desde la vista tampoco me muestra la imagen con:

```
{{ object.image.url }}
```

al inspeccionar el html muestra la ruta pero no carga la imagen y siempre muestra el mensaje ALT.

Los archivos estáticos (en este caso imágenes) que tengo en la aplicación si que los puedo mostrar mediante

```
{% static "/ruta/imagen.jpg" %}
```

Pero necesito mostrar las imagenes cargadas sin poner rutas estáticas de éste modo.

Cualquier sugerencia será agradecida.

EDITADO + AÑADIDO

Lo que tengo al respecto en settings.py

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
]

MEDIA_URL =  '/media/'

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
```

Comment: incluiste la configuracion de media en settins.py?

Comment: deberias tener algo asi: ...MEDIA_URL = '/media/'.....
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: He intentado modificar la configuración de settings pero sin éxito...

Comment: para visualizar la imagen debes agregar una url que apunte a media

Comment: url(r'^media(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, })

Comment: eso iria en tu urls.py principal

Comment: tambien revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280056/page-not-found-404-django-media-files

Comment: Mil gracias @Tegito123, lo he solucionado con el enlace último que me has proporcionado.